# Documentation review items should also include an "Improve" button

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation, review-queues

I've built a small habit around improving edits while reviewing if I feel like the revision or addition was 95% the way there. With the new Documentation review queues going up, this feature is missing.

Could we have it in?

Comment: Agreed, would be nice to have this.  Should probably only be available for silver/gold tag badge holders though, as you really need immediate approval privileges for this flow to work.