# Indicate that a Proposed Change has reject votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, proposed-changes

I can understand not showing previous review decisions for a change, to prevent the previous thoughts from helping to influence new ones. But I think it would be useful to *at least* show reject votes on a pending proposed change.

Reject votes point out flaws for a change. If the reviewer is not familiar with the tag, they may miss a big problem. If they don't check for it, they may miss that it's a duplicate or copied content. Even leaving a comment does not mean the reviewers will notice or care, with comments at the bottom of the page and not really standing out much.

For instance, with the "duplicate" reason, if someone comes through who is not as acquainted with the documentation's tag, they may not realize a topic/example already exists. They may not go looking, and they may not notice comments on the matter.

As an example, a duplicate example was approved in [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) since the review queue rolled out. Myself and another user in the tag had already rejected, prior to the queue release, for the example being 1) a duplicate and 2) in the wrong topic. When I checked in this morning, all the proposed changes were cleared. When I checked, I was bewildered to see this example had been approved, *despite* my comment (which had been there a long while) stating what was wrong with it.

I had proposed changes in to delete a couple duplicate examples. I can't help but wonder if this would have happened if there had been some kind of indicator that this was an issue, aside from a comment on one of them that no one (except another regex reviewer from before the queue was out) seems to have read.

For another example, with "copied content", it could be (and probably already has been) the same scenario as with "duplicate". If you do your due diligence, and another reviewer does not, they may not notice/read/care about any comment you post on the matter and instead approve the copied change.

"Incorrect", "other", and "too specific" are all things an unfamiliar reviewer could easily miss, especially other.

The only review reason that should be easy for *anyone* to see without being pointed out is "vandalism", and even then someone will almost certainly miss it sooner rather than later.

Documentation is different than Q&A. While Q&A edits should be able to be reviewed without knowledge in the subject, in most cases, Documentation should be the opposite and almost always require subject knowledge to verify the edit does not invalidate the example/topic or make them incorrect. Since documentation is meant to be *correct* rather than just an attempt at someone explaining something they think they know (as answers are) we need to empower reviewers without subject knowledge with that little bit extra information they may not have, and may not catch even if they do briefly search on the internet for the correctness of the change.

If the team is completely against showing *all* rejections, "duplicate" and "copied content" *at least* should be shown, to give reviewers a heads up that they should check the suggested duplicate or the potential plagiarism before reviewing.

If, as suggested in the comments, it's decided only users over a certain rep threshold should be able to see these votes, the minimum rep to review docs should be raised to meet this level. The reviewers really should be able to see this, in case something important is pointed out in the reject reason but not in the comment section, or in case the reviewer misses the comment.

Something about this needs to be done. Documentation should be accurate in technical detail. Since the review queue does not limit who can review what tags*, we have to have a way to show the reviewers that *don't* catch the comments and *don't* know the material there is something off about the proposed change. [This is still an issue,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338886/banner-on-proposed-changes-that-have-a-reject-vote-for-copied-content) and something needs to be done. Showing the red "reject" message to future reviewers seems like a good place to start.

---

<sub>* I do not feel we *should* limit the queue, for example by tag score. Some of us have a hard time finding questions worth answering in the tags we are interested in. However, if this remains a problem, I would gladly support this more extreme measure to help ensure the quality of Documentation topics and examples.</sub>

<sub>As a side note, since the introduction of the review queue, I have rolled back four changes that should not have been made in the regex documentation, and I am debating whether another new one needs rolled back. There have been about 20 regex changes proposed, and approved, since the queue was added and *zero* rejected. That number includes the changes that I made to roll back changes that should have been rejected. This feels like too high of a false positive rate.</sub>

Comment: I'd like to ask for extending this request to rejections in general. In my experience, the rejection is - mostly - either valid or blatantly wrong. Many rejections are something you do not necessarily immediately notice. … But well … It's also an indicator for people not taking review seriously.

Comment: @bwoebi I've expanded the request. Let me know if you see anything else I should add.

Comment: If the rejections are not shown - it would at least be nice if a link (indicator) is included in the review title so one realized that there were comments attached to the edit (and can just click right to the heading).

Comment: @JGreenwell I think that's _just_ different enough to be a different request. Even if rejects are shown, it would still be nice to have an indicator of comments. I've seen instances where a comment makes sense but I'm not fully committed to either a rejection or an approval.

Comment: @JGreenwell I already have a request for that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329219/documentation-proposals-there-are-comments-please-do-not-approve-straight-ahea

Comment: @bwoebi yes, but that would need an addendum or update based on the review queue (i.e. how would it fit in there and adding " _ Comments on this post" after the title would be a start. Also, I agree with Kendra that sometimes a comment, say "you misspelled X", says to me - don't vote yet give them a chance to retract and resubmit the edit

Comment: @JGreenwell That's rather what we shall have an _Accept and Improve_ button for, which is status-planned: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334302/documentation-review-items-should-also-include-an-improve-button

Comment: I understand that they might not want to show if something was rejected, so another suggestion would be to make the rejected reason into a comment, sort of what suggested duplicate flags do now. This will give the hint that something was rejected, but it won't say straight out that it was.

Comment: @TotZam That could be a solution, in that case, though as my "duplicate" example shows, it might not help much. It seems like the only user who read that comment was the other regex user who rejected before the queue came about.

Comment: I agree with showing rejection votes. We show close votes on questions in Q&A. How would showing rejections on proposed changes be different? I guess there's a rep difference (need 3K to see close votes), so maybe make it a rep-based thing?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If we make it rep based, the reviewing privilege for docs should be raised to that level as well. If you're reviewing, I think you should be made aware of the reject votes on the proposal you're reviewing. If you're looking at something you don't have domain knowledge of, since documentation is a bit different and should be correct, it's best you're made aware of issues you may not be able to catch or other examples or topics it may be duplicating.

Comment: Definitely a good point. I do think reviewing Docs should have a higher rep requirement than it does now. 100 rep doesn't really demonstrate that much knowledge of how the system works, especially with Docs being different from Q&A, as you say.

Comment: Completely  agree and so do others. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329972/1175966 Not showing other reviewers votes makes no sense and is just asking for even more crap to be approved

Comment: It would certainly give robo reviewers more signal to base their 2second review choice on

Comment: If robo reviewers bothered to read it and react accordingly, I would hesitate to call them "robo". Perhaps "semi-robo", but if they take the time to read the warnings, and instead of hitting the fast and easy "accept" button they actually select reject... That's a step in the correct direction. Not entirely perfect, as they should try to judge the validity of the statement or skip, but better than something that should be rejected and has votes as such being approved without a second thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was just pushed out.

Now, you'll see any reject votes while the proposed change is being reviewed.

I've also made it so you'll see your own "approve" votes on in-progress reviews, too, as it was a little unclear before (only the "approve" button was green, but disabled).