# Banner on proposed changes that have a reject vote for "copied content"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, plagiarism, proposed-changes

Often when I leave comments on proposed changes, it's to inform other reviewers that I've caught plagiarism. For instance:

> Copied from: https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/254267-Vista-File-Associations

Unfortunately, it's displayed *below* the proposed change at the bottom of the page. Let me bring up some of my Words of Wisdom™:

> ## Never underestimate the value in forcing a user to scroll past something.

<sup>([Source](/a/338220/6388243))</sup>

I believe that having a banner showing above the proposed change when someone has rejected as Copied Content could prove quite beneficial. Something like:

> This change may have been **inappropriately copied** from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming

For best results, have the link open in a new window so that both can be viewed at the same time.

Users new to Documentation reviewing (and not used to putting every new example into a search engine) would find out, before they look the proposed change, that another user has caught plagiarized content, and reject accordingly. As opposed to how it is now, where the proposed change that I left that comment on was approved 4:3 by <1K users and I had to roll it back.

[Another example of this exact thing happening.](//stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114312)
[Yet another example.](//stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114498)

Comment: Also potentially solved by [my proposal to show reject votes on changes.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334371/indicate-that-a-proposed-change-has-reject-votes)

Comment: So… what's the point of downvoting this?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I only linked my related post. Though it could be that people don't like the idea of a banner being displayed to show this. It might be they feel it's too in-your-face, or otherwise don't think it would be a good way to fix the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta especially the part about "Voting is different on Meta".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I know that—I'm asking why, exactly, this is a "bad" feature request.

Comment: Well, you asked "what's the point?"; that link answers "to express disagreement with the feature request". If you had asked "why not do this feature request, o downvoter?" I would not have commented, as Kendra has explained it well.

Comment: I linked your proposal in mine, for your examples of things that are still coming through and shouldn't. Something definitely needs done about all of this, whether it's your idea, mine, or something else.

Comment: And now the majority of the comments here are about the two downvotes on the post itself. Good ol' meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been enabled now.

If a change has a rejection vote for copied content, and is still eligible for review, the following banner will appear:

[image]

If there are multiple copied content votes, and the have different links, each link will displayed.  Any non-link comments will be listed as plain text.