# Why are some reviews not visible in documentation review before the review is completed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, proposed-changes

In the documentation review, some users' reviews are visible only after the review is completed, while other reviews are visible at any time after they get submitted. Here is an example:

As shown in the following screenshot, first p... approved this change, then z... rejected it and then I approved it:

[image]

However, the following screenshot shows that when I open the review, I can only see z...'s review and my own review, but not p...'s review:

[image]

A little bit later, the review was completed and then I could see all reviews on the change, including p...'s review:

[image]

The strange thing is that I could only see p...'s review once the review was completed, although p... reviewed the change first. However, I could see z...'s review already before the review was finished.

One thing I've noticed is that both z... and a... have more than 1k reputation (a... has 4k and z... has 3k), and p... only has approximately 400, so this might be related to reputation. It might also be related to the fact that p... approved the change and z... rejected it.

This is not the only example I've come across, there are many other similar cases. This just happened to be the example that I came across when I wanted to post this question.

Why could I see z...'s review before the review was completed, but could only see p...'s review after the review was completed? Is this a bug? Is it related to the users' reputation? Is it related to who approved it and who rejected it? Is there any other reason? If it's a bug, please fix it. If it's intentional, please explain why I can see some reviews but not others and the reason for why it's that way.

Comment: Related (and the reason for this starting): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334371/indicate-that-a-proposed-change-has-reject-votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this was intentional but confusing (retagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because it was literally so confusing we didn't realize it was intentional -_-).

In essence:

- we want to show any reject votes *immediately*
- we also want to explain why you can't review a second time

These two combined into a very weird rule that basically meant you could always see reject votes, and never see approve votes *unless* you were the one who cast the only approve vote.

Starting with the next build we will instead show all reject votes, and put a tooltip on the disabled approve or reject button if you've already reviewed.

[image: Tooltip and rejections]